# Get user sim number android

Tags: android, android-settings

In my application, I want to get user's sim number if present, i have tried below code but it returns ""

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = 
(TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Required permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

I have searched everywhere to find a method to get user's sim number but nothing worked for me. Some people saying maybe user's sim provider have restriction over this feature but I use imo application that get my sim number and displays in application so I have tried different methods on same mobile but nothing works, if anyone know working method kindly tell me.

Comment: No way to get Sim number. You can think, if your application can get your phone number, all applications will do that.

Comment: how imo do that ?

Comment: @RoShan Shan It is not phone number , it is sim number which is of 14 digits. Try `tMgr.getSimSerialNumber()`.

Comment: I think he wants to get phone number `String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();`

Comment: i don't need serial number, i need sim/phone number where i can send text message to verify user's identity

Comment: Oh then you can't do that. The only way you can get phone number is by requesting user to send an sms to your server which uses some third party service to recieve sms and get the number

Comment: Check this answer for third party services http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890318/how-to-verify-the-phone-number-similar-to-whatsapp.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Add the Required Permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE">
</uses-permission>
```

**Note:** For Devices with 6.0 (marshmallow) and above Use [**Run Rime Permissions**](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

**Step 2:**

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    String sim1= telephonyManager.getLine1Number();  

    String sim2= telephonyManager.getLine2Number();
```

Check [this](http://myandroidtuts.blogspot.in/2013/05/fetching-users-mobile-number-android_8.html) for More info

Comment: returns empty string

Comment: What is Your device Model..??

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134398/telephonymanager-getline1number-failing/5134725#5134725

Answer (score 1):

First of all i suggest that you should use shared preference,you just store it and use it in your app wherever you want. it is the easiest way i guess.

**OR**

try to check in

> Phone--> Settings --> About -->

Phone Identity, If you can  to view Number there, then may be you can get the number. but if you can not view the phone number in the settings, then you won't be able to get via this code.

Comment: yes tried it and it shows unknown, i am just wondering how imo application  access my number on same device

Comment: @Martin then i dont think it is possible for your app sir.

Answer (score 1):

Enable permission in Manifest ,get your SMI Number and Imei Number

Manifest.Java

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

MainActivity.Java

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     Activity mActivity; 
     String mStatus;
    private TextView mSmiTxt;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mActivity = MainActivity.this;
        mSmiTxt = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.smitxt);
mStatus=loadSMI1();
 mSmiTxt.setText(mStatus);

            /** Fading Transition Effect */
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        }
      /**
         * Called when the 'loadIMEI' function is triggered.
         */
        public void loadIMEI() {
            // Check if the READ_PHONE_STATE permission is already available.
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // READ_PHONE_STATE permission has not been granted.
                requestReadPhoneStatePermission();
            } else {
                // READ_PHONE_STATE permission is already been granted.
                loadImei();
            }
        }
      public String getDeviceUniqueID() {
            String device_unique_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
            return device_unique_id;
        }

        private void requestReadPhoneStatePermission() {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
                // Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
                // and the user would benefit from additional context for the use of the permission.
                // For example if the user has previously denied the permission.
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Permission Request")
                        .setMessage(getString(R.string.permission_read_phone_state_rationale))
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                //re-request
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
                            }
                        })
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.error)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // READ_PHONE_STATE permission has not been granted yet. Request it directly.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
            }
        }
     /**
         * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
         */
        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                               @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

            if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE) {
                // Received permission result for READ_PHONE_STATE permission.est.");
                // Check if the only required permission has been granted
                if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // READ_PHONE_STATE permission has been granted, proceed with displaying IMEI Number
                    //alertAlert(getString(R.string.permision_available_read_phone_state));
                    loadImei();
                } else {
                    alertAlert(getString(R.string.permissions_not_granted_read_phone_state));
                }
            }
        }
     public String loadImei() {
            //Have an  object of TelephonyManager
            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            //Get IMEI Number of Phone  //////////////// for this example i only need the IMEI
            String IMEINumber = tm.getDeviceId();
            return IMEINumber;
        }
     private void alertAlert(String msg) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("Permission Request")
                    .setMessage(msg)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // do somthing here
                        }
                    })
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.error)
                    .show();
        }

     public String loadSMI1() {
            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String sim1 = tm.getLine1Number();
            return sim1;
        }


    }
```

If the SMI number returns null ,get it from whatsapp

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />


AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
Account[] accounts = am.getAccounts();

ArrayList<String> googleAccounts = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Account ac : accounts) {
    String acname = ac.name;
    String actype = ac.type;
    // Take your time to look at all available accounts
    System.out.println("Accounts : " + acname + ", " + actype);
}
if(actype.equals("com.whatsapp")){
    String phoneNumber = ac.name;
}
```

Comment: Martin, try this one                                                                   TelephonyManager telemamanger = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String getSimSerialNumber = telemamanger.getSimSerialNumber();
String getSimNumber = telemamanger.getLine1Number();

Comment: it gives an error "cannot resolve symbol oneTelephonyManager"

Comment: Pass your activity like this TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) 
    getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);